# Passing RTS-opts to `stack test`

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

How can I pass RTS options to the test-suite of my project using stack?

`stack exec` allows for passing options to the executable, but since `stack test` is a synonym for `stack build --test` I can't see how to accomplish this.

I'm trying to generate some JSON-formatted profiler output for my test-suite using the RTS option `-pj` ([GHC user guide](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/profiling.html#rts-flag--pj)).

I can see where stack places the regular executables, but not the executables for the test-suite.

Comment: Can't you pass `--ghc-options -pj`?

Comment: It's not an option to GHC. GHC compiles with `+RTS` adding `-p` as a flag to the binary that it builds. I need to pass the flag to the executable.

Comment: On my phone right now, but `--test-arguments` may work for this.

Comment: I think that's almost right. It reports that it's called with these options: `test (suite: test, args: +RTS -p -RTS -pj)` but from the .prof-file that it creates it looks like `-p` has squelched `-pj`